# I have trouble understanding the functionality of mat-checkbox 'checkboxLabel()' function

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material, label

Htmlfile

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </tr>
</table>
```

ts file

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Table with selection
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-selection-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-selection-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-selection-example.html',
})
export class TableSelectionExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  /** The label for the checkbox on the passed row */
  checkboxLabel(row?: PeriodicElement): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.position + 1}`;
  }
}
```

I want to understand how the checkboxLabel() functionality is working. I am trying to choose selected rows by using this function, but it is printing multiple times on console the row that I choose.

If I am selecting the first rows, then in the checkboxLabel() function, it is appearing mutiple times, I want to use a particular value from that row and I am unable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First, while I am not an accessibility expert, I think `aria-label` isn't about the state (ie. checked or unchecked) of the checkbox, but should contain the label which describes the checkbox. To show the checked state, you should use [`aria-selected`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-selected).
For design reasons, I would add a separate `mat-label` and link it with [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) to the checkbox.

Second, you don't have to use the same method to define the labels of your table header, and your table rows, ie. you could have a `headerCheckboxLabel` and a `rowCheckboxLabel`, that would make those methods a bit cleaner, eg. no optional param.

Third, the reason of the method being called multiple times is the change detection in angular. That's a broader topic than what can fit into an answer, it is worth to read more about it, but the essence is that whatever is in the template bindings, will get evaluated upon every change detection. So if you have a method in the bindings, that will be called many times, especially if you have it in an `ngFor` or on the `*matCellDef` of the `mat-table`.